# Chrome Download works, but Resource interpreted as Document, not as zip File

Tags: google-chrome, jsf, download

My JSF Application should download a zip file by clicking a button, while this is happen the UI should be blocked. The Download works fine, but Chrome has problems with the response and so the UI never stops to be blocked.

Here is the Response Code:

```
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = FacesUtil.getServletResponse();
    httpResponse.setContentType("application/zip");
    httpResponse.setContentLength((int) (new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + fileName)).length());
    httpResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
            InputStream is = null;
    OutputStream os = null;

    try {
        os = httpResponse.getOutputStream();
        is = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + fileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        int anz = 0;
        while ((anz = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, anz);
        }

        is.close();
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();

    } catch (IOException e) {
```

And here the xhtml:

```
                <h:commandButton  id="downloadDokumenteBtn" action="#{dokumenteUebersicht.downloadDokumente}"  value="Ausgewählte Dokumente downloaden" onclick="jQuery.blockUI()">
                </h:commandButton>
```

Chrome has now a problem and with the Developer Tools you can see the reason:

**

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type
>   application/zip.

**

I tried a lot (CommandLink, sorts of forms, a4j:CommandLink), nothing works...

Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: Have you observed this in other browsers?

Comment: Yes, the UiBlock also does not stop at IE11. But i figured out that this are 2 different problems. First one, the Chrome behaviour is still a miracle, second that the blockUi does not stop seems to be a "work as designed", because there is no way for this framework to check that the download part is done.

Comment: Try moving `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();` up a little bit; maybe immediately after getting the `HttpServletResponse`. What exactly does `FacesUtil` do?

Comment: FacesUtil is quite simple:

 public static HttpServletResponse getServletResponse() {
  return (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
    .getExternalContext().getResponse();
 }